# 0x800706F7 - The stub received bad data on server 2008

Tags: c++, stub

Recently we moved our application from server 2003 to server 2008 (32 bit) but it is throwing an error while calling a server method. The server method is written in C++. Here is the code:

CLIENT SIDE CODE:

```
String[] arrNames = new String[]{}; 

System.Object []objArr =  new System.Object[]
{
  string, string, string, string, string, arrNames
};

// Get data for report

System.Object vntRet = QApplication.instance().DataSpace.invoke_Service
                    ( m_oFormService, "getReportData", objArr );
```

SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
getReportData(BSTR bsDocTypeId, BSTR bsReportObjectId, BSTR bsCustomerId, 
                          BSTR bsDeliveryTypeId, BSTR bsCountryId, SAFEARRAY ** pparrRsNames, SAFEARRAY ** pparrRs)
```

Where `pparrRs` is return parameter.

I went through various posts but couldn't find any valid solution. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the issue. My server code was trying to get the images from other blob server and due to the large image size it was throwing an exception.

Comment: Thank you for updating your own post with an answer rather than leaving once you figured it out. It's much appreciated.